# Boundary of a part of the sphere

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I am asking myself what is the boundary of the set
$$
M:=\{\vec{x}=(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\in S^{n-1}: x_i>0\textrm{ for all }1\leq i\leq n\}?
$$
(Here $S^{n-1}:=\{\vec{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n: \lVert\vec{x}\rVert=1\}$ denotes the sphere.)

I think the boundary $\partial M$ of $M$ consists of those $\vec{x}=(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\in S^{n-1}$ with at least one and at most $n-1$ entries $0$ and the remaining entries positive.

Example: $n=3$. I think
$$
\partial M=A\cup B\cup C\cup D,
$$
where
$$
A:=\left\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)\right\}
$$
$$
B:=\left\{(x_1,x_2,0): x_1,x_2>0\textrm{ and }x_1^2+x_2^2=1\right\}
$$
$$
C:=\left\{(x_1,0,x_3): x_1,x_3>0\textrm{ and }x_1^2+x_3^2=1\right\}
$$
$$
D:=\left\{(0,x_2,x_3): x_2,x_3>0\textrm{ and }x_2^2+x_3^2=1\right\}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the definition of Boundary point taken below,

$$\textbf{x} \in S \text{ is boundary point } \leftrightarrow \forall \epsilon >0 \hspace{0.2cm}  \Big( V_{\epsilon}(\textbf{x}) \cap S \neq \phi \Big) \land \Big( V_{\epsilon}(\textbf{x}) \cap \bar{S}  \neq \phi \Big) $$ where $V_{\epsilon}(\textbf{x})$ is $\epsilon$ neigborhood around $
\textbf{x}$

then if  $ M = \{ \textbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n : ||\textbf{x}|| = 1 , x_i >0 \}$ then its boundary is following

$$\partial M = \{ \textbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n : ||\textbf{x}|| = 1 , x_i \geq 0 \}$$

Comment: And thus, each element in $\partial M$ has at least one entry 0 (while the others are positive) and at most $n-1$ entries 0 while the remaining is $1$?

Comment: @John_Doe Think of simple 2-D case you will see that for every neighborhood drawn around the point in the circle there is always a point on the circle and a point not on the circle

Comment: I thought that the set $M$ is the interior and the set $\partial M$ is the boundary and then $\bar{M}=M\cup\partial M$ so that the set $\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n: \lVert x\rVert=1,x_i\geq 0\right\}=\bar{M}$ is the closure but not the boundary.

Comment: @John_Doe note that interior of $M$ is empty !!. can you see why ?

Comment: I am completely confused, sorry!

Comment: @John_Doe interior of set $S$ are those points for which there is neighborhood around that point that is completely in the set  $S$

Comment: So you are telling me that $\partial M = \bar{M}=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:\lVert x\rVert=1, x_i\geq 0\}$.

Comment: @ if $n=2$ then $M$ is quarter circle in first quadrant except points on $x$ and $y$ axes.then apply the definitions whatever you know on this . you will get intuition

Comment: I think I did understand that $\partial M=\bar{M}=\{\textbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n: \lVert\textbf{x}\rVert=1, x_i\geq 0\}$.

Comment: thank you very much